# Dymo.Connect.SDK does not list printers in ClickOnce app

Tags: c#, winforms, dymo

I'm using the new DYMO SDK Dymo.Connect.SDK provided by NuGet in a Windows Forms app (.Net Framework 4.8). I want to list all available dymo printers. When debugging the app or starting the exe, everything works fine and the printer is found. When I deploy the app as ClickOnce, no printer is found.

My Code:

```
using DymoSDK.Implementations;
public static List<string> GetLabelWriterList(bool tape = true)
    {
        List<string> printers = new List<string>();
        foreach (DymoSDK.Interfaces.IPrinter printer in DymoPrinter.Instance.GetPrinters()) //Get list of DYMO printers installed
        {                                 
             printers.Add(printer.Name);                    
        }
        return printers;
   }
```

What might be the reason for ClickOnce to fail?

Comment: Did you find a resolution for this? Facing the same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Did you find a resolution so far?

Comment: Hi, not with this SDK, no - I switched to the old SDK available from http://download.dymo.com/dymo/Software/Download%20Drivers/LabelWriter/Downloads/13/WIN_DLS_SDK_0508.EXE and was able to get things working with this.

Comment: found your bug report, for anyone who is interested: https://github.com/dymosoftware/DCD-SDK-Sample/issues/29?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the deployed dlls. The following dlls were not deployed into the click once application files folder: DYMOPrinting, PrintingSupportLibrary, libdymobarcode and libSkiaSharp. I could add DYMOPrinting, PrintingSupportLibrary manually from packages\DYMO.Connect.SDK.1.3.2.137\Build. libdymobarcode.dll couldn't be added from there and libSkiaSharp.dll also fails.
With dlls DYMOPrinting and PrintingSupportLibrary deployed, the ClickOnce app is now able to display the available printers. However printing still fails, because libSkiaSharp is missing. I don't get this.

Comment: Has anyone figured this out? Maybe the Nuget restore isn't getting all the files? I have tried rolling back to 1.3.2.137 and GetPrinters() returns no printer.  The newer version throws an exception (Access is denied).  The example project from Dymo does the same as my code.